# optimized rolling functions on irregular time series with time-based window

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

Is there some way to use rollapply (from `zoo` package or something similar) optimized functions (`rollmean`, `rollmedian` etc) to compute rolling functions with a time-based window, instead of one based on a number of observations? What I want is simple: for each element in an irregular time series, I want to compute a rolling function with a N-days window. That is, the window should include all the observations up to N days before the current observation. Time series may also contain duplicates.

Here follows an example. Given the following time series:

```
      date  value
 1/11/2011      5
 1/11/2011      4
 1/11/2011      2
 8/11/2011      1
13/11/2011      0
14/11/2011      0
15/11/2011      0
18/11/2011      1
21/11/2011      4
 5/12/2011      3
```

A rolling median with a 5-day window, aligned to the right, should result in the following calculation:

```
> c(
    median(c(5)),
    median(c(5,4)),
    median(c(5,4,2)),
    median(c(1)),
    median(c(1,0)), 
    median(c(0,0)),
    median(c(0,0,0)),
    median(c(0,0,0,1)),
    median(c(1,4)),
    median(c(3))
   )

 [1] 5.0 4.5 4.0 1.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.5 3.0
```

I already found some solutions out there but they are usually tricky, which usually means slow. I managed to implement my own rolling function calculation. The problem is that for very long time series the optimized version of median (rollmedian) can make a huge time difference, since it takes into account the overlap between windows. I would like to avoid reimplementing it. I suspect there are some trick with rollapply parameters that will make it work, but I cannot figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: There's no way to do this with `rollapply`. You could roll your own function (pun intended) using `window`.

Comment: Is this question and answer of any assistance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465998/sliding-time-intervals-for-time-series-data-in-r

Comment: `rollapply` "cheats" by calling `rollmedian` if you use `median` as the FUN.  Compare: `system.time(rollapply(runif(100000), 5, function(x) median(x)))` to `system.time(rollapply(runif(100000), 5, median))` (former is 30x slower).  If you want speeds comparable to what `rollapply` achieves without "cheating" I can provide some solutions.  Additionally, `rollmedian` also "cheats" in as much as it requires odd observations, so clearly it's just defining an index of the "middle" values, which is trivial compared to what you are trying to do.

Comment: See this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134823/r-faster-way-to-calculate-rolling-statistics-over-a-variable-interval/20137464#20137464) for a fast Rcpp rollmean function with a time-based window.

Comment: Is it possible to make the time series regular by filling with NA's, then apply a rolling window of a fixed size to that?

Comment: It seems to me that @rbatt' suggestion might work (and has been proposed in similar solutions). I've played around with a function that fills your irregular time-series with NAs and computes the rolling median on that data. For a data.frame with 10,000 irregular observation this computation takes about 3.8 seconds (on a slow CITRIX client).

Answer (score 5):

As of version v1.9.8 (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016), [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) has gained the ability to perform *non-equi joins* which can be used here.

The OP has requested

> for each element in an irregular time series, I want to compute a
> rolling function with a N-days window. That is, the window should
> include all the observations up to N days before the current
> observation. Time series may also contain duplicates.

Note that the OP has requested to  include all the observations up to N days before the current *observation*. This is different to request all the observations up to N days before the current *day*.

For the latter, I would expect *one* value for `1/11/2011`, i.e., `median(c(5, 4, 2))` = 4.

Apparently, the OP expects an *observation*-based rolling window which is limited to N days. Therefore, the join conditions of the non-equi join have to consider the row number as well.

```
library(data.table)
n_days <- 5L
setDT(DT)[, rn := .I][
  .(ur = rn, ud = date, ld = date - n_days), 
  on = .(rn <= ur, date <= ud, date >= ld),
  median(as.double(value)), by = .EACHI]$V1
```

> ```
> [1] 5.0 4.5 4.0 1.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.5 3.0
> ```

---

For the sake of completeness, a possible solution for the *day*-based rolling window could be:

```
setDT(DT)[.(ud = unique(date), ld = unique(date) - n_days), on = .(date <= ud, date >= ld), 
   median(as.double(value)), by = .EACHI]
```

> ```
>          date       date  V1
> 1: 2011-11-01 2011-10-27 4.0
> 2: 2011-11-08 2011-11-03 1.0
> 3: 2011-11-13 2011-11-08 0.5
> 4: 2011-11-14 2011-11-09 0.0
> 5: 2011-11-15 2011-11-10 0.0
> 6: 2011-11-18 2011-11-13 0.0
> 7: 2011-11-21 2011-11-16 2.5
> 8: 2011-12-05 2011-11-30 3.0
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("      date  value
 1/11/2011      5
 1/11/2011      4
 1/11/2011      2
 8/11/2011      1
13/11/2011      0
14/11/2011      0
15/11/2011      0
18/11/2011      1
21/11/2011      4
 5/12/2011      3")[
   # coerce date from character string to integer date class
   , date := as.IDate(date, "%d/%m/%Y")]
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend using [runner](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runner/index.html) package which is optimized to do operation requested in this topic. Go to section **Windows depending on date** in [documentation](https://gogonzo.github.io/runner/), for further explanation.

To solve your task, one can use `runner` function which can execute any R function in running windows. One-liner here:

```
df <- read.table(
  text = "date  value
   2011-11-01      5
   2011-11-01      4
   2011-11-01      2
   2011-11-08      1
   2011-11-13      0
   2011-11-14      0
   2011-11-15      0
   2011-11-18      1
   2011-11-21      4
   2011-12-05      3", header = TRUE, colClasses = c("Date", "integer"))

library(runner)
runner(df$value, k = 5, idx = df$date, f = median)
[1] 5.0 4.5 4.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.5 3.0
```

---

P.S. one should be aware that 5-days window is `[i-4, i-3, i-2, i-1, i]` instead of `(i-5):i` (6-days window). Illustration below for better explanation of the concept.
I've made example on 5-days window but if one want to reproduce result as OP requested, can specify 6-days window:

[image: running date windows]

```
identical(
  runner(df$value, k = 6, idx = df$date, f = median),
  c(5.0, 4.5, 4.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5, 3.0)
)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

**1) rollapply** Haven't check the speed but if no date has more than `max.dup` occurences then it must be that the last 5 * max.dup entries contain the last 5 days so the one-line function `fn` shown below passed to `rollapplyr` will do it:

```
k <- 5

dates <- as.numeric(DF$date)
values <- DF$value

max.dup <- max(table(dates))

fn <- function(ix, d = dates[ix], v = values[ix], n = length(ix)) median(v[d >= d[n]-k])

rollapplyr(1:nrow(DF), max.dup * k, fn, partial = TRUE)
## [1] 5.0 4.5 4.0 1.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.5 3.0
```

**2) sqldf** We can use an SQL self-join to do this.  We join to each `a` row those `b` rows no more than 5 days back and then group by the `a` row taking the median of the `b` rows joined to it.

```
library(sqldf)

k <- 5
res <- fn$sqldf("select a.date, a.value, median(b.value) median
       from DF a
       left join DF b on b.date between a.date - $k and a.date and b.rowid <= a.rowid
       group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
res$median
## [1] 5.0 4.5 4.0 1.0 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.0 2.5 3.0
```

**Note:** We used this for `DF`:

```
 Lines <- "
      date  value
 1/11/2011      5
 1/11/2011      4
 1/11/2011      2
 8/11/2011      1
13/11/2011      0
14/11/2011      0
15/11/2011      0
18/11/2011      1
21/11/2011      4
 5/12/2011      3
"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers suggest to insert NA to make the time series regular. 
However, this can be slow in case of long time series. Additionally, it does not work for functions which can not be used with NA.

The width argument of rollapply (zoo package) can be a list (see help of rollapply for details). Based on this I wrote a function which creates a list to be used with rollapply as width parameter. The function extracts indexes for irregular zoo objects if the moving window is to be time and not index based. Therefore the index of the zoo object should be the actual time.

```
# Create a zoo object where index represents time (e.g. in seconds) 

d <- zoo(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,16,25,27,27,27,27,27,31),     
         c(1:5,11:15,16,25:30,31))

# Create function 

createRollapplyWidth = function(zoodata, steps, window ){   

  mintime =  min(time(zoodata))     

  maxtime =  max(time(zoodata)) 

  spotstime = seq(from = mintime , to = maxtime, by = steps)

  spotsindex = list() 

    for (i in 1:length(spotstime)){
    spotsindex[[i]] =  as.numeric(which(spotstime[i]  <=  time(zoodata) & time(zoodata) < spotstime[i] + window))}

  rollapplywidth = list()
    for (i in 1:length(spotsindex)){
    if (!is.na(median(spotsindex[[i]])) ){ 
      rollapplywidth[[round(median(spotsindex[[i]]))]] = spotsindex[[i]] - round(median(spotsindex[[i]]))}
  }
  return(rollapplywidth)
  }


# Create width parameter for rollapply using function

rollwidth =  createRollapplyWidth(zoodata = d, steps = 5, window = 5) 

# Use parameter in rollapply 

result = rollapply(d, width = rollwidth , FUN =  sum, na.rm = T) 
result
```

Limitation: not based on dated but on time in seconds. Parameter "partial" of rollapply does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my tinkering with the problem. If that sort of gets at what you wanted (I don't know if it's satisfactory in terms of speed), I can write it up as a more detailed answer (even though it's based on @rbatt's idea).

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

# create a long time series
start <- as.Date("1800-01-01")
end <- as.Date(Sys.Date())

df <- data.frame(V1 = seq.Date(start, end, by = "day"))
df$V2 <- sample(1:10, nrow(df), replace = T)

# make it an irregular time series by sampling 10000 rows
# including allowing for duplicates (replace = T)
df2 <- df %>% 
  sample_n(10000, replace = T)

# create 'complete' time series & join the data & compute the rolling median
df_rollmed <- data.frame(V1 = seq.Date(min(df$V1), max(df$V1), by = "day")) %>% 
  left_join(., df2) %>% 
  mutate(rollmed = rollapply(V2, 5, median, na.rm = T, align = "right", partial = T)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(V2)) # throw out the NAs from the complete dataset
```