# Rolling window function for irregular time series that can handle duplicates

Tags: r, date, time-series, rolling-computation

I have the following data.frame:

```
    grp  nr   yr
 1:   A 1.0 2009
 2:   A 2.0 2009
 3:   A 1.5 2009
 4:   A 1.0 2010
 5:   B 3.0 2009
 6:   B 2.0 2010
 7:   B  NA 2011
 8:   C 3.0 2014
 9:   C 3.0 2019
10:   C 3.0 2020
11:   C 4.0 2021
```

Desired output:

```
   grp  nr   yr nr_roll_period_3
1    A 1.0 2009               NA
2    A 2.0 2009               NA
3    A 1.5 2009               NA
4    A 1.0 2010               NA
5    B 3.0 2009               NA
6    B 2.0 2010               NA
7    B  NA 2011               NA
8    C 3.0 2014               NA
9    C 3.0 2019               NA
10   C 3.0 2020               NA
11   C 4.0 2021         3.333333
```

The logic:

- I want to calculate a rolling mean for the period of length k (let's say 3), where 3 includes the current month/year/day (by group)
- However, this shouldn't calculate anything where there is no 3 consecutive years/months/days
- Likewise, whenever there is NA in the column for calculation within this period, the output should be NA.

Currently I have this function:

```
calculate_rolling_window <-

  function(dt, date_col, calc_col, id, k) {

    require(data.table)

    return(setDT(dt)[
      , paste(calc_col, "roll_period", k, sep = "_") := 
        sapply(get(date_col), function(x) mean(get(calc_col)[between(get(date_col), x - k + 1, x)])),
      by = mget(id)])

  }
```

It works fine for the regular cases, where there is no duplicates in the date column. However, with duplicates it fails:

```
    grp  nr   yr nr_roll_period_3
 1:   A 1.0 2009         1.500000
 2:   A 2.0 2009         1.500000
 3:   A 1.5 2009         1.500000
 4:   A 1.0 2010         1.375000
 5:   B 3.0 2009               NA
 6:   B 2.0 2010               NA
 7:   B  NA 2011               NA
 8:   C 3.0 2014               NA
 9:   C 3.0 2019               NA
10:   C 3.0 2020               NA
11:   C 4.0 2021         3.333333
```

Any ideas on how to handle this? No need for exclusively `data.table` approach.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15960352/optimized-rolling-functions-on-irregular-time-series-with-time-based-window

Comment: Thanks, however have tried the approaches, and cannot fit into current requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be solved by *grouping in a non-equi join* to aggregate over a rolling window of length `k`, filtering for `k` consecutive years, and an *update join*:

```
library(data.table)
k <- 3L
# group by join parameters of a non-equi join
mDT <- setDT(DT)[.(grp = grp, upper = yr, lower = yr - k), 
                 on = .(grp, yr <= upper, yr > lower), 
                 .(uniqueN(x.yr), mean(nr)), by = .EACHI]
# update join with filtered intermediate result
DT[mDT[V1 == k], on = .(grp, yr), paste0("nr_roll_period_", k) := V2]
DT
```

which returns OP's expected result:

> ```
>     grp  nr   yr nr_roll_period
>  1:   A 1.0 2009             NA
>  2:   A 2.0 2009             NA
>  3:   A 1.5 2009             NA
>  4:   A 1.0 2010             NA
>  5:   B 3.0 2009             NA
>  6:   B 2.0 2010             NA
>  7:   B  NA 2011             NA
>  8:   C 3.0 2014             NA
>  9:   C 3.0 2019             NA
> 10:   C 3.0 2020             NA
> 11:   C 4.0 2021       3.333333
> ```

The intermediate result `mDT` contains the rolling mean `V2` over `k` periods and the count of unique/distinct years `V1` within each period. It is created by a *non-equi join* of `DT` with a data.table containing the upper and lower bounds which is created on-the-fly by `.(grp = grp, upper = yr, lower = yr - k)`.

```
mDT
```

> ```
>     grp   yr   yr V1       V2
>  1:   A 2009 2006  1 1.500000
>  2:   A 2009 2006  1 1.500000
>  3:   A 2009 2006  1 1.500000
>  4:   A 2010 2007  2 1.375000
>  5:   B 2009 2006  1 3.000000
>  6:   B 2010 2007  2 2.500000
>  7:   B 2011 2008  3       NA
>  8:   C 2014 2011  1 3.000000
>  9:   C 2019 2016  1 3.000000
> 10:   C 2020 2017  2 3.000000
> 11:   C 2021 2018  3 3.333333
> ```

This is filtered for rows which contain exactly `k` *distinct* years:

```
mDT[V1 == k]
```

> ```
>    grp   yr   yr V1       V2
> 1:   B 2011 2008  3       NA
> 2:   C 2021 2018  3 3.333333
> ```

Finally, this is joined with `DT` to append the new column to `DT`.

Note, that `mean()` returns `NA` by default if there is an `NA` in the input data.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(text = "rn    grp  nr   yr
 1:   A 1.0 2009
 2:   A 2.0 2009
 3:   A 1.5 2009
 4:   A 1.0 2010
 5:   B 3.0 2009
 6:   B 2.0 2010
 7:   B  NA 2011
 8:   C 3.0 2014
 9:   C 3.0 2019
10:   C 3.0 2020
11:   C 4.0 2021", drop = 1L)
```